# Recycler View is not Working or Showing Up

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I am trying to take data from API and save it in Array List which is used in Recycler View adapter. But it's not showing. As user searches, on every text change an API call gets generated and we get data from API that I am trying to add that data into the same array List that has been used to create Recycler View adapter, and Recycler view is under the search bar so as it shows up as suggestion returned from API search like autocompleteTextView.

Here is the code:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private EditText et_DataInput;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<stockSuggestionModel> stockSuggestionList;

    // There we are adding Data in Array
    public void addElement(stockSuggestionModel element){
        stockSuggestionList.add(element);
    }

    stockSuggestAdapter suggestAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et_DataInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_inputData);

        // ArrayList
        stockSuggestionList = new ArrayList<>();

        // recycler view
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.searchSuggestion);

        // Adapter redefining;
        suggestAdapter = new stockSuggestAdapter(MainActivity.this, stockSuggestionList);
        // It is used to tell in which form our layout will be.
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        // set Adapter
        recyclerView.setAdapter(suggestAdapter);


        //To make the search facility which captures (one by one variable).
        et_DataInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                String quearyString = et_DataInput.getText().toString();

                // if else condition for blank
                Log.i(TAG, "Search: " + quearyString);
                // There we have created
                // There we are adding data to the ArrayList to Show-Up
                FetchStock fetchStock = new FetchStock();
                fetchStock.execute(quearyString);

            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

        });
    }

}
```

FetchStock:

```
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);

            // There can be a  problem as there is Two Data name variable.
            JSONArray data = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

            for (int i=0; i < data.length(); i++){

                // Instance of Model Class
                stockSuggestionModel StockSuggestionModel = new stockSuggestionModel();

                // JsonObject to really get Data
                JSONObject itemsArray = data.getJSONObject(i);

                // variable to transmit data
                String symbol = null;
                String instrument_name = null;
                String exchange = null;

                try {
                    symbol = itemsArray.getString("symbol");
                    instrument_name = itemsArray.getString("instrument_name");
                    exchange = itemsArray.getString("exchange");
                } catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if(symbol != null && instrument_name != null){
                    StockSuggestionModel.setStockName(instrument_name);
                    StockSuggestionModel.setStockSymbol(symbol);

                    String instrument = StockSuggestionModel.getStockName();
                    Log.i(TAG, "Data Has adding into the array used by adapter");
                    Log.i(TAG,""+instrument);
                    // adding data into the arrayList
                    MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
                    mainActivity.addElement(StockSuggestionModel);
                }

            }
```

stockSuggestionModel.java:

```
public class stockSuggestionModel {

    String stockName;
    String stockSymbol;

    public stockSuggestionModel(String stockName, String stockSymbol) {
        this.stockName = stockName;
        this.stockSymbol = stockSymbol;
    }

    public stockSuggestionModel() {
    }

    public String getStockName() {
        return stockName;
    }

    public void setStockName(String stockName) {
        this.stockName = stockName;
    }

    public String getStockSymbol() {
        return stockSymbol;
    }

    public void setStockSymbol(String stockSymbol) {
        this.stockSymbol = stockSymbol;
    }
}
```

stockSuggestAdapter.java

```
public class stockSuggestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<stockSuggestAdapter.viewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<stockSuggestionModel> stockSuggestionArrayList;

    public stockSuggestAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<stockSuggestionModel> stockSuggestionArrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.stockSuggestionArrayList = stockSuggestionArrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public stockSuggestAdapter.viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.suggest_items, parent, false);
        stockSuggestAdapter.viewHolder StockSuggestAdapter = new stockSuggestAdapter.viewHolder(view);
        return StockSuggestAdapter;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull stockSuggestAdapter.viewHolder holder, int position) {
        stockSuggestionModel StockSuggestion = stockSuggestionArrayList.get(position);
        holder.stockName.setText(String.valueOf(StockSuggestion.stockName));
        holder.stockSymbol.setText(String.valueOf(StockSuggestion.stockSymbol));

        // We also need a Func when User Click on our List. (userAdapter of Java Messenger has implementation of this)

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return stockSuggestionArrayList.size();
    }

    public class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView stockName;
        TextView stockSymbol;

        public viewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            stockName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.stockName);
            stockSymbol= itemView.findViewById(R.id.stockSymbol);

        }
    }
}
```

If needed anything else, please ask and Thanks in advance.

Trying to take data from API and add it into the Array List used by Recycler View in order to show recycler view under the search bar as autoCompleteTextView Effect.

Comment: Doesn't look like your notifying adapter of data change ( `notifyDataSetChanged` ) when adding to list: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49006430/17856705).  (The adapter does not observe changes - it must be told there have been changes to underlying list.)

Comment: how should I write the code for it can you please give an example?

Comment: The code is `suggestAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` - but you would want to do this after the JSON data loop in `FetchStock`- this will cause a redraw of all recycler views.  If you were only modifying a single element then there are other notification methods to call.

Comment: You also have an error in the `FetchStock` - you should not be creating `MainActivity` at all - you need a reference.  The OS is responsible for creating activities.  Pass `MainActivity.this` as parameter to the constructor - this would be one way.  Or pass in the `stockSuggestionList` and let it populate it directly.

Comment: I created a func in MainActivity as `public void notifyDataSetChanged(){ suggestAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); }` and then in FetchStock after For loop `mainActivity.notifyDataSetChanged();` called the func but It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a new arrayList save your fetch stock and pass it to suggestAdapter's stockSuggestionArrayList(stockSuggestionArrayList = newList), then call notifyDataSetChanged() in adapter.